# Subquery returned more than 1 value inside where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi guys I've been trying to do this SQL, but it shows this message. I don't know why because the condition has a IN to search in the subquery, but gets stuck on it.

**The query**

```
SELECT PRO.ID_PRODUCTO,
PRO.ID_CATEGORIA,
PRO.DESCRIPCION AS DESCRIPCION
FROM T_PRODUCTO PRO  WHERE PRO.ID_CATEGORIA in (
      CASE WHEN @ID_CATEGORIA = '0' 
      THEN PRO.ID_CATEGORIA 
      ELSE 
      (Select [Data] 
      from dbo.fnSplit('1,3,4,5',',')
      )
```

**The message**

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Comment: It might be a misleading message.  The first part of your subquery does not have a select clause.

Comment: i put the select clause but doesnt change anything, but keeps showing the message

Comment: @DanBracuk The message is not misleading. A `CASE` expression can return one value per row, it can't return a `SELECT` with more than one, which the `ELSE` is doing now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When used in a `CASE` statement, your subquery is being evaluated as an expression.

You can apply the case statement in a different manner (as it's based on your `@ID_CATEGORIA` variable):

```
SELECT PRO.ID_PRODUCTO,
PRO.ID_CATEGORIA,
PRO.DESCRIPCION AS DESCRIPCION
FROM T_PRODUCTO PRO  WHERE
(
  @ID_CATEGORIA <> '0' 
  AND PRO.ID_CATEGORIA IN ( 
    SELECT [Data] FROM dbo.fnSplit('1,3,4,5',',')
  )
)
OR
(
  @ID_CATEGORIA = '0'
  AND PRO.ID_CATEGORIA = PRO.ID_CATEGORIA
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  PRO.ID_PRODUCTO,
        PRO.ID_CATEGORIA,
        PRO.DESCRIPCION AS DESCRIPCION
FROM T_PRODUCTO PRO  
WHERE @ID_CATEGORIA = '0' 
OR PRO.ID_CATEGORIA IN (SELECT [Data] 
                        FROM dbo.fnSplit('1,3,4,5',','))
```

Comment: I try this but when is 0 dont retrieve anything :/

Comment: I would like to see the query you are using in that case. And also some sample data to see if the behavior can be replicated